# Apache HTTP: Conditionally Set the Last-Modified header

Tags: apache-2.2, http, http-headers

I want to set the *Last-Modified* date with one of these values:

- If the request header has the *If-Modified-Since* value, use this value
- Else use current date

How can I configure this in apache's **httpd.conf**?